# Booting from a live usb kali linux in persistance mode in both a laptop and a VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I have a usb stick with kali linux in persistance mode that I use on my laptop. However, I would also like to use with my PC in a VM with The same live persistance mode(I would prefer Virtualbox, as I'm familiar with it) and to keep the changes between the devices. What are my options?

Comment: Can't you just use the usb stick as you normally would but in virtualbox? I suppose that when you create an empty machine, you can set it up to boot from usb, then you procede as usual